# Wordpress Meta Query - multiple keys

Tags: wordpress, meta

I am writing a meta query for search purpose. I have total 16 keys (fields) from which I need to search the keyword. So far I am retrieving results from 4 keys (keys). But when I am extending code for all the fields I get the error. Kindly point out the mistake and also the right approach to go.
*The code that is working fine:*

```
$WorkinFilter_k_s = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'Building_Name',
                'value'   => '',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'Street',
                'value'   => $keywords1,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'Town',
                'value'   => $keywords1,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'Description',
                'value'   => $keywords1,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

*The code when I extend for all 16 fields. It is not working*:

```
$WorkinFilter_k_s = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'Street',
                    'value'   => $keywords1,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'COMMENTS1',
                    'value'   => $keywords1,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE')
                ),
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'COMMENTS3',
                    'value'   => $keywords1,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'Town',
                    'value'   => $keywords1,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
                )
                ),
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'Building_Name',
                    'value'   => $keywords1,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
                array(
                    'key'     => 'Description',
                    'value'   => $keywords1,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
                ),
                array('relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'District',
                    'value'   => $keywords1,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'BulletPoint5',
                    'value'   => $keywords1,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE')
                    )
                )
            ),  
            array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'BulletPoint2',
                    'value'   => $keywords1,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'BulletPoint3',
                    'value'   => $keywords1,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE')
                ),
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'BulletPoint1',
                    'value'   => $keywords1,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'BulletPoint6',
                    'value'   => $keywords1,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
                )
                ),
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'BulletPoint7',
                    'value'   => $keywords1,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
                array(
                    'key'     => 'BulletPoint8',
                    'value'   => $keywords1,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
                ),
                array('relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'BulletPoint9',
                    'value'   => $keywords1,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'),
                array(
                    'key'     => '',
                    'value'   => $BulletPoint10,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE')
                    )
                )
            ) 

        )
    );
```

Comment: I never checked it but Wordpress will probably only read 2 levels deep. You have a bunch of depths, which are all redundant because all your relations are `OR`. So you should actually only write everything 1 level deep. It all looks a bit messy in general. Also, this query is likely to become very slow because Wordpress does not know how to optimise it. A raw query could do better but you probably need to learn more about SQL first.

Comment: I am using OR because I want the keyword if it is present in anyone of the fields. I know I have done wrong structuring. That is what I am asking, if someone could correct me.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely to still work inefficient but you mostly just have to clean up your code.

```
$WorkinFilter_k_s = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'Street',
            'value'   => $keywords1,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'COMMENTS1',
            'value'   => $keywords1,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'COMMENTS3',
            'value'   => $keywords1,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'Town',
            'value'   => $keywords1,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'Building_Name',
            'value'   => $keywords1,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'Description',
            'value'   => $keywords1,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'District',
            'value'   => $keywords1,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'BulletPoint5',
            'value'   => $keywords1,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'BulletPoint2',
            'value'   => $keywords1,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'BulletPoint3',
            'value'   => $keywords1,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'BulletPoint1',
            'value'   => $keywords1,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'BulletPoint6',
            'value'   => $keywords1,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'BulletPoint7',
            'value'   => $keywords1,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'BulletPoint8',
            'value'   => $keywords1,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'BulletPoint9',
            'value'   => $keywords1,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
);
```